# SQL, JDBC "Invalid column index" error with simple query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, struts2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to STRUTS and JDBC, my application tries to connect to a simple DB that has 3 tables, right now all is doing is trying to query 1 table that only stores "first, last names and a Id field"

```
System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

            try {
                connection = 
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","david","changeit");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }
```

where I would like to get the result of 1 column if a match occurs:

```
            String sql = "SELECT S_ID FROM Students WHERE firstname=? AND lastname=?";

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, firstname);
            ps.setString(2, lastname);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                studentid = rs.getString(1);
                ret = SUCCESS;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { ...
```

As far as I can tell the connection is made, 
the SQL query

```
Select s_id from Students where firstname='first' and lastname='last';
```

when run on SQL Dev. works and gives me a single result.

I don't really get a stack trace the code just jumps from right before the 'while (rs.next()) {..' directly into the finally block

```
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = ERROR;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is line 83?

Comment: hmm actually is a number, but when ran the code doesn't even go inside the while loop while (rs.next()) { ...

Comment: yes firstname and lastname are populated correctly I debugged it.

Comment: Did you try debugging to ensure firstname and lastname are populated correctly?

Comment: Regarding your comment about not going into the `while(rs.next())` loop, where else are you calling `getString()` from? Because that is where the error seems to be coming from.

Comment: yes I tried to see if there was anything there.. that's why I got that particular exception. I used to get an exception but not anymore.. however it seems that the query is not being successful

Comment: If the result is coming back with nothing, and your Java and SQL Dev are looking at the same database, then there seems to be something wrong with the query.

Comment: @Ascalonian the query is fine when I ran it on SQLdev

Comment: @Ascalonian here I can see in debug mode the first and last name inside ps>preparedStatement>parameterString: http://i.imgur.com/N4D3Jn1.png

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Oracle drivers work. But below statement is what i see on Oracle site. Are you getting a **non empty resultset** ?
As you are not getting a nullpointerexception on .next(), i'm wondering if Oracle drivers return an empty ResultSet, which may lead to this problem.

> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm
>
> In case of a standard JDBC driver, if the SQL string being executed
>   does not return a ResultSet object, then the executeQuery method
>   throws a SQLException exception. In case of an Oracle JDBC driver, the
>   executeQuery method does not throw a SQLException exception even if
>   the SQL string being executed does not return a ResultSet object.

Comment: I think this might be the problem. It seems that the query is fine.. when I ran it on SQLdev and the connection seems fine (it fails if I enter the wrong password). I don't know what it could be :(

Comment: Does the SQL returns at least single row when you run on SQLDev ?
Please bear with me, your code i do not see any issue.
Can you put a break point at rs = ps.executeQuery(); and see the value being assigned to rs ?

Comment: yes I can, this is the state of ps right before that line: http://i.imgur.com/OUpN64q.png

Comment: and here we can look at the first and last name inside ps>preparedStatement>parameterString: http://i.imgur.com/N4D3Jn1.png

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'm at work and imgur is blocked. I would check as soon as i get home. Hope someone can help you in the meantime.

Comment: Glad that i could be of some help. Please add your findings here if possible. It might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said I'm new at using this.
The problem was that my schema didn't have the CONNECT role assigned to it.

Solution log in as 'SYSTEM' and grant the role to my schema

```
grant connect to MY_SCHEMA;
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!